# SWT - drawing with floating point coordinates and subpixel precision

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Canvas provided by SWT offers only int coordinates. It is enough for simple task, but sometimes the floating point precision is needed. Of course, the number of pixels would stay the same, but it is possible to create an illusion of point being "between the pixels" by using different shades of original color and proper antialiasing. But implementing such rendering mechanism is nontrivial. I wonder if there are any third party solutions already avaiable/recommended?

(so far only found [SWTGraphics2D from Piccolo](http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/piccolo/learn/piccolo/doc-1.2/api/edu/umd/cs/piccolox/swt/SWTGraphics2D.html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution (because of library being included in JDK since Java 1.7) is to use the FXCanvas from JavaFX (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swt/FXCanvas.html), which could be embedded in SWT components structure. JavaFX provides drawing methods that use double as coordinates instead of int.